# Assembly Loop Error

Tags: assembly, masm

I am trying to write a program in assembly (masm) that will accept a user input and the program will output a count starting from 0 up to that input (between 0 to 99). The error I am encountering is that no matter what number I enter, the program loops to what seems to be a random number and then terminates. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
cseg segment 'code'
assume cs:cseg, ds:cseg, ss:cseg, es:cseg

    org 100h

    start:
    mov ah, 09
    mov dx, offset Intro
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01
    int 21h
    sub al, 30h

    mov bl,0Ah
    mul bl
    mov bl, al

    mov ah, 01
    int 21h
    sub al, 30h

    add bl, al
    mov cl, bl
    jmp again

    again:
    mov ah, 09
    mov dx, offset Hello
    int 21h
    mov dx, offset msg1
    int 21h
    mov dx, offset msg
    int 21h
    inc byte ptr msg
    mov al, msg

    cmp al, 3ah
    jg reset
    loopne again
reset:mov byte ptr msg, 30h
    inc byte ptr msg1
    cmp cx, 0
    jg again
    jmp done

    done:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

    org 200h
    Intro db "Please input how many times you would like the loop to run." , 20h, 20h, "$"
    Hello db "hello world" , 20h, 20h, "$"
    msg db 30h, 13, 10, "$"
    msg1 db 30h, "$"
    cseg ends
    end start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loopne` instruction uses the `CX` register and you only initialized the `CL` register which is the low byte of `CX`. If you insist on using `loopne`, clear `CH` which is the high byte of `CX`.

Of course the solution is much simpler.
Keep the logic of modifying the textual counter independant of the logic of the main loop. The worst that will happen is that the textual counter will have been incremented once for nothing.
Also there's no benefit in moving the user inputted value in `CX`. You can just as well or even better work with it from `BL`.

```
 add  bl, al              ;BL has user input 00..99
again:
 mov  ah, 09
 mov  dx, offset Hello
 int  21h
 mov  dx, offset msg1
 int  21h
 mov  dx, offset msg
 int  21h

      ; This is the textual counter update
 inc  byte ptr msg        ;Raise the ones
 mov  al, msg
 cmp  al, "9"
 jbe  SameDecade
 mov  byte ptr msg, "0"   ;Reset the ones
 inc  byte ptr msg1       ;Raise the tens
SameDecade:

      ; This is the main loop counter update
 sub  bl, 1
 jnb  again

 mov  ax, 4C00h           ;DOS.TerminateWithExitcode
 int  21h
```

Answer (score 0):

two problems:

1. you're assigning `bl` to `cl`, without clearing `ch` part, its better to use something like `movzx cx, bl`
2. you're not changing cx, before comparison, add `dec cx` before `cmp cx, 0`

just advice: you do not need to use `jmp again` or `jmp done`

Comment: `dec cx` already sets flags (as if from `cmp cx,1` *before* decrementing, if you want to be specific about how it sets flags for `jg`); `dec cx / jnz` is a useful idiom.  (It doesn't set CF, of course, so it's not quite the same as `cmp`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes right, I've just followed initial code where cx is explicitly tested

Comment: I'm suggesting you could say "replace `cmp cx,0` / `jg` with `dec cx` / `jnz`".  But actually, I'm not *sure* that's right for the program.  I didn't follow the whole logic; maybe they intended to not touch the loop counter in the `reset` case, and effectively retry the same iteration of the main loop.  (Which does use `loopne` if the jump to `reset` isn't taken.)  Would make much more sense to just use `jge` / `loop` instead of having `loopne` also check flags and fall through on the `== 0x3a` case, though.